# How to force LaTeX to place a figure exactly where I want

Tags: floats, listings, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Force figure placement in text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8625/force-figure-placement-in-text)
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

How can I force LaTeX to insert a figure exactly where I want.

Here's the code I use:

```
\lstset{framexleftmargin=0mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black},basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,breaklines,
columns=fullflexible}
\begin{figure} [htbp!]
\begin{lstlisting}
root@bt:~# nmap -O www.we****t***.com

Starting Nmap 6.01 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2012-12-21 15:38 CET
Nmap scan report for www.we****t***.com (217.6*.***.**)
Host is up (0.0087s latency).
Not shown: 990 filtered ports
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
21/tcp   open   ftp
22/tcp   open   ssh
53/tcp   open   domain
80/tcp   open   http
110/tcp  open   pop3
143/tcp  open   imap
443/tcp  open   https
587/tcp  closed submission
3306/tcp open   mysql
Device type: general purpose
Running (JUST GUESSING): Linux 2.6.x (90%)

Aggressive OS guesses: Linux 2.6.22 (90%),
OpenWrt Kamikaze 7.09 (Linux 2.6.27) (89%),
Linux 2.6.18 - 2.6.24 (89%),
Linux 2.6.23 (86%)

No exact OS matches for host (test conditions non-ideal).

OS detection performed.
Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 79.16 seconds
\end{lstlisting}
\caption{Nmap -O}
\end{figure}
```

LaTeX places the figure on another page which is astonishing since it makes the whole work ugly.

Here's the preamble I use:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,singleside,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{ia_urb_thesis}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage {listingsutf8}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[thinlines]{easytable}
\usepackage{upquote}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\usepackage{listings}
%\lstset{language=PHP}
\usepackage{url}
%\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
%\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\titolo{...Injection ...
\\[5mm]}
\candidato{xxx}
\relatore{Chiar.mo xxxx}
\annoaccademico{2011-2012}

\copertinatesi

\dedica{Ai miei genitori}
\indice
\indicefigure
\indicetabelle
\iniziatesto

\include{cap_1}
\include{cap_2}
\include{cap_3}
\include{cap_4}

\appendix
\include{app_a}
\include{biblio}

\ringraziamenti
Vorrei ringraziare ...

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Could Frank Mittelbach's answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) be of any help?

Comment: You should use the inherent structure provided by [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings), which allows you to say `\begin{lstlisting}[...,float=H,caption={..}]`. For this you would also need the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float).

Comment: See also [Force figure placement in text](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/8625) (duplicate, perhaps)

Comment: Just don't put it in a `figure` environment. The _whole_ purpose of the figure environment is to be a _floating_ environment and move to a suitable place to avoid bad page breaks.

Comment: I need to use the figure environment since I believe is the only way to get a caption starting from a listings environment...

Comment: @g9999 then you obviously haven't read the posts that **Torbjørn T.** and **Marc van Dongen** pointed you to, especially [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8631/11002).

Comment: Not exactly, read Werner's comment, and/or search the `listings` documentation for the word "caption".